# Is list-initialization an implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, list-initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

};

class Derived: public Base { };

int main(){

    int arr[10];
    Derived d;
    Base *p = &d;

    std::map<std::type_index, std::string> proper_name = {
        {typeid(int), "int"}, {typeid(double), "double"}, {typeid(float), "float"}, {typeid(char), "char"},
        {typeid(Base), "Base"}, {typeid(Derived), "Derived"}, {typeid(std::string), "String"},
        {typeid(int[10]), "Ten int Array"}, {typeid(p), "Base Pointer"}};

}
```

I'm trying to make sense of the implicit conversions that occur in this list-initialization. From `13.3.1.7` of N3337:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> 1. Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> 2. If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

`8.5.4`:

> A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_list<E>` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list<E>` for some type `E`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments

So [the following](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) list of constructors for `std::map` indicates

`map (initializer_list<value_type> il,
     const key_compare& comp = key_compare(),
     const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())`;

is the candidate function, `value_type` in this case is `pair<const type_index, std::string>`. Lastly from `13.3.3.1.5`:

> If the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` or “array of `X`”135 and all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to `X`, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an element of the list to `X`.

So it is a valid conversion as long as the elements of the braced-list implicitly convert to `pair<const type_index, std::string>`. But those elements are also braced-lists themselves. `Pair` does not take an initializer-list constructor, [from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) it seems that copy-initialization from a braced-init list uses the second part of `13.3.1.7` to construct the object. So the following:

```
pair<const type_index, std::string> p = {typeid(int), "int"}
```

becomes:

```
pair<const type_index, std::string> p(typeid(int), "int")
```

but is this considered an implicit conversion? How can use of a two-argument constructor be considered an implicit conversion? What are the standard's comments on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conclusion that

```
pair<const type_index, std::string> p = {typeid(int), "int"};
```

becomes

```
pair<const type_index, std::string> p(typeid(int), "int");
```

is not accurate because the first statement is *copy-list-initialization* while the second is *direct-initialization*. The two are identical, except that *copy-list-initialization* is ill-formed if an `explicit` constructor is chosen (and narrowing conversions are not allowed in the former).

So if the `pair` constructor in question was defined as

```
template<class U1, class U2>
explicit constexpr pair(U1&& x, U2&& y);
```

*direct-initialization* would still succeed, but *copy-list-initialization* would fail. Quoting from right below the parts of *[over.match.list]* you quoted

> In copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

---

Other than that, everything else you've said is correct. The `pair` constructor is an implicit conversion because the constructor is not `explicit` and it's considered for overload resolution according to the second bullet of *[over.match.list]* because `pair` doesn't have an initializer list constructor.

Comment: Nitpick: "The two are identical, except that copy-list-initialization is ill-formed if an explicit constructor is chosen", [except when the initializer list has a single element whose type is the same or derived from the type of the object being initialized](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) (which might get an exception to the exception to the exception if [there's an initializer_list constructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2137)).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I didn't know about either of those. But now that the first issue has a resolution, what I said is still correct, isn't it? The two differences are explicit constructors and narrowing conversions.

Comment: Yes, I think, for now. Copy-list and copy-vanilla are more different.